# Is there a keyboard shortcut for Visual Studio to invoke the class constructor for a new object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor, autocomplete, new-operator

I'd like a way to quickly instantiate a new object in C# using Visual Studio when defining an object variable. Lets say I type the following code

```
Object someObject =
```

Is there a way to auto-complete the line of code with a one or two keystroke combination to achieve the code below?

```
Object someObject = new Object();
```

Currently I end up auto-completing the new keyword, then auto-completing object class, and then tabbing outside of the auto-generated parenthesis and typing the semi-colon. I know this is probably minimal already(six keystrokes?), but I'd love a way to auto-complete these statements more intelligently that IntelliSense already does.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I hope my answer helps. Please remember to mark answers as accepted.

Comment: When I type `object someObject = ne`, I just type [tab] (which completes "new") and then [tab] again which adds `object();`. But I have ReSharper installed, so that my be adding to my intellisense,

Comment: It seems like base IntelliSense handles it similarly, except that I need to type 'n [tab] [space] [tab] ( [tab] ;'

I'm not a huge fan of ReSharper, mainly because it's gotten bloated lately and also takes weeks of configuration to get to my liking. It seems like this is the best solution so far though.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title, this is really simple to do. There's no keyboard shortcut but you can type `ctor` then hit tab twice.

I think what you wanted to ask was "Is there a quick 'IntelliSense' way to declare and instantiate an object?"

The answer to this is yeah, type it out and use IntelliSense!

Just as @Rufus L says, the quickest way to do this is by using IntelliSense the way you could. In your example if you typed 'ne' then tab, you'd likely get the `new` keyword, then begin typing 'Obj', then tab again and IntelliSense will know the type your after based on what you've already typed and whack it in for you.

For this example, IntelliSense isn't really showing off its great capabilities. You'll learn to use IntelliSense to speed all sorts of things up pretty quickly and it's a neat helper for us developers.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: For me, this adds `CancellationTokenRegistration` :*(

Comment: @Rufus, that's because the ctor shorthand is for generating a _constructor_ for a class, not initialising an object.

Comment: I see, that is cool! But isn't the OP asking for a way to *invoke* the constructor, rather than create one?

Comment: And to what your thinking, my answer answers. ;)

Comment: I'm aware of the ctor code-snippet, but that keyword defines the class constructor for the class you're working in. I'm trying invoke the constructor of another class.